# Simulate Download in Flash Builder

Tags: download, flash-builder, simulate

in Flash IDE we can compile our SWF and then click in View->Simulate Download but I can't see that option in Flash Builder, is not possible to simulate a download with Flash Builder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flash builder is not able to simulate download speeds. For that you will need a browser plugin..

Comment: what do you mean with a browser plugin? I have Flash Player installed in my browser of course, but I can't simulate download with it.

Comment: I meant something like this: http://www.uselessapplications.com/en/Application/FirefoxThrottle.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I found a way from another user:
http://www.ultrashock.com/forum/viewthread/91428/
"I got the simulation I was looking for with a local web server and running Charles with bandwidth throttling…. But it would still be nice to get this result with Flex Builder"

But I was searching the way for simulating download from FB :(